# selecting value from Combobox dropdown using selenium and c#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#-4.0, combobox, dropdown

I am working on automation of an application with selenium and c#. How to select value from combobox dropdown?

HTML code:

```
<div ng-class="{deleted: row.entity.isDeleted, dirty: row.entity.isDirty()}" <div="" ng-repeat="col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-000T dirty editable" ui-grid-cell="" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="true">
                        <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope ui-grid-cell-focus ui-grid-cell-contents-hidden">Medicare Advantage Plan</div><div ng-class="{deleted: row.entity.isDeleted, dirty: row.entity.isDirty()}" class="ng-scope dirty">
```

I tried the below code and its not working.

```
_context.WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='ui-grid-row ng-scope'][" + (i) + "]/div/div[3]")).SendKeys("Medicare Advantage Plan");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a list of elements of the drop-down element and then by index you can access them. In order to create the list you need to check the drop-down elements and find a common element like id/name/xpath. I made something similar in Java, hope it helps.

```
public void getList_ByXpath(String element, int list_index_to_click) {
        try {
            getWait().until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(element)));
            WebElement web_el = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(element));
            Select select = new Select(web_el);
            List<WebElement> option = select.getOptions();
            option.get(list_index_to_click).click();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

You need to create an WebElement that will find elements based on a common identifier, then the list is created and you do the action you want based on index.

Comment: Drop-down elements are dynamic , there are no predefined dropdown elements.

Comment: Also i tried with SelectElement, for which i got unexpected tag exception